# Plotting load displacement diagram with some details

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I'm trying to draw this picture with tangent lines and labels but when I use `sqrt(x)` function(I don't know the exact function) I get a diagram like picture:
[image]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:6] 

    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (6.2,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,6.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \draw[color=blue]   plot (\x,{1.5*sqrt(2*\x)})    node[right] {$f(x) = \sqrt x$};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I get a diagram like this picture with tangent lines and notations:
[image]

Comment: Offtopic: except from the first "straight line"... the others doesn't seem to be "tangential"... Ontopic: Also your code compiles fine for me (on sharelatex... Test it again there to see if your problem is local on your pc)

Comment: That's right the picture is not perfect!

Comment: Found your error... (You possibly used : `\sqrt` instead of `sqrt` on your compiled code... but the one posted here has not that problem)... I get the same output if I change your function...

Comment: How can I add the tangent lines?

Comment: Yuo can just edit your question and fix the error... Then the answer is easy (just a math derivative and some simple calculations)... But this moment any answer will be offtopic (Your question is about empty diagram right now)

Comment: do you have gnuplot installed? Instead you can just use `\draw[red] plot (\x,{sqrt(\x)})  node[right] {$f(x) =\sqrt x$};`

Comment: How can I add details like attached picture?

Comment: As koleygr already stated in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426766/plotting-load-displacement-diagram-with-some-details#comment1067793_426766) you could add a tangent to the graph if you *know* the function you plot as e.g. shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358028/95441). If you *don't know* the function you could add a tangent as e.g. shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292865/95441).